# Realm migration from a required variable to nullable

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

Realm migration from a required variable to nullable

I had a variable which was a REQUIRED field in my previous version of realm. But for the newer version i want it to be not required but a nullable one. How do i do it through realm migration?

Answer (score 8):

You can check the example in [migrationExample](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java) provided by Realm team

```
if (oldVersion == 2) {
   RealmObjectSchema personSchema = schema.get("ClassName");
   personSchema.setNullable("nullableFielName", true);
}
```

If you have already synced with Realm Object Server, please check this: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#syncing-migrations

Comment: Have done it already. An error occurs 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode: -Property 'nullableFielName' has been made optional'

Comment: Okay this issue is with Realm Object Server.

Comment: This is a "destructive" schema operation so the only thing you can do is add a new field that is nullable, and I *think* you can define a migration that would apply a transform for the data into the new field. Removing the current field from code *should* keep it in the schema, but "hide" it from the API.

Comment: @Ankur You can follow the link in the updated answer for more information about updating schema on Realm Object Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the table in realm by either doing this
First you declare your variable as optional

```
open class YourModel: RealmObject() {
@SerializedName("english") var english: String? = "" }
```

and then do this in your migration file

```
 override fun migrate(realm: DynamicRealm?, oldVersion: Long, newVersion: Long) {
    val schema = realm?.schema
    if (oldVersion < 1L) {
                schema?.get("YourModel")
                        ?.removeField("english")
                        ?.addField("english", String::class.java)}
```

or

```
 schema?.get("YourModel")
                   ?.setNullable("english",true)}
```