# How to change Realm property to nullable?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How to change `CalendarEvent.notes` to optional (nullable)?

```
class CalendarEvent: Object {
    @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var notes: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var notification: String = ""
}
```

The Realm database is already populated with data.
I want the `notes` property to be changed to nullable in the Realm database.
If I try `@objc dynamic var notes: String? = ""` a runtime error appears stating `Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'CalendarEvent.notes' has been made optional.`

According to the Realm documentation, renaming a property during a migration is a way to acheive this. Is it possible to change this property to nullable and without renaming?

Comment: try this `@objc dynamic var date: String?`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik this causes a runtime error stating `Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'CalendarEvent.notes' has been made optional.`

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356943/12688502

Comment: you have to update the schema version like` let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 2)`

Comment: I am trying to perform this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48899642/10555547 but in Realm swift instead

Comment: Please check : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just handle this in the migration block and using the same property name is fine. Here's the code that would migrate a non-optional first_name property to an optional first_name property.

The original object looks like this

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var first_name = ""
```

and then we change the property to optional

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var first_name: String? = nil
```

and here's the migration block to do that. The first version was 1 (with the non-optional first_name) and version 2 is has the updated object.

```
let vers = UInt64(2)
let config = Realm.Configuration( schemaVersion: vers, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
     print("oldSchemaVersion: \(oldSchemaVersion)")
     if (oldSchemaVersion < vers) {
        print("  performing migration")

        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: PersonClass.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
            newItem!["first_name"] = oldItem!["first_name"]
         }
     }
 })
```

This will leave the existing data intact. We use this kind of migration all of the time as our app needs change.

Comment: Thanks Jay, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This is not working for Int or Bool. How to make an Int or a Bool property nullable?

Comment: Hi @mefahimrahman - it's been a couple of years since this post and Realm is now using Persisted vars instead of the objc, but an optional bool is defined as `@Persisted var value: Bool?` and an optional Int is `@Persisted var value: Int?`. Please see the documentation for [Supported Property Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#supported-property-types). We use bools and ints all the time so if it's not working for you, perhaps a posting a question with your code an a description of the issue would help.